# How to get instance of actual form from MS Access in a Module (VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a bunch of forms in MS Access 2010. All of them are bound forms but I tricked them to only save once I click `btnSave`.

The main problem is that I have quite a lot of code that is the same for every form in some events such as `form_beforeUpdate()` or `form_afterUpdate()` or `form_Load()`. An example:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click()
 'Check first that all fields have been filled
 If CheckAllFields = True Then
     Exit Sub
 End If
 TempSaveRecord = True
 Me.Dirty = False 'this will make an attempt of form_Update()
 Form_Load 'After Saving we restart the data
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
 If TempSaveRecord = False Then
   Me.Undo
   Exit Sub
 End If
End Sub
```

`CheckAllFields` is just a routine that checks whether all the required fields are not `null`:

```
Private Function CheckAllFields() As Boolean
  Dim Ctrl As Control
  CheckAllFields = False

  'Check for unfilled fields
  For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
     If Ctrl.Tag = "required" And IsNull(Ctrl) Then
                MsgBox "The field " & Ctrl.Name & " has not been filled."
        CheckAllFields = True
        Exit For
     End If
  Next Ctrl
End Function
```

I would like to do all of this in just one Module, but I can't find a way to get the actual instance of the form in that moment. Any help would be greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this all the time.

Here is one example:

```
'in a main module
Public Sub mFormLoad(p_form As Form)
    'do stuff with p_form
end sub
```

Then, in the actual form itself:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    mFormLoad Me
End Sub
```

---

For your example, change your function to be both public and add the argument for the form:

```
public Function CheckAllFields(p_form as form) As Boolean
  Dim Ctrl As Control
  CheckAllFields = False

  'Check for unfilled fields
  For Each Ctrl In p_form.Controls
     If Ctrl.Tag = "required" And IsNull(Ctrl) Then
                MsgBox "The field " & Ctrl.Name & " has not been filled."
        CheckAllFields = True
        Exit For
     End If
  Next Ctrl
End Function
```

and then change the line you call it to be:

```
If CheckAllFields(me) = True Then
```

Comment: Great! Thank you @enderland it works perfect, I should have asked this before, now I have 20 forms to update.

Comment: @EricPb I know what you mean, I had similar problems and one day just broke down and spent a.... while updating all of them to have something like this. Trust me, you will be thankful (especially since I have callbacks for most open/close/current events which are identical on many forms).

Answer (score 0):

To get the active form you could use the following code.

```
Screen.ActiveForm.Name
```

Then you can create a new object and set it to the ActiveForm.

```
Public obj_Form As Access.Form
Set obj_Form = Forms!MyActiveForm
```