# How to get the properties of the current active form from a class module?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I currently have 2 forms that contains a `List Box` of records with some `Text Box` to allow user input. I have a `Command Button` that inserts the data input into a table, then I requery the `List Box` which is **bounded** to the table get the updated data.

The functionality code in both forms are the same so I like to reduce as much repetitive code as possible and am basically trying to do something like this issue:

[How to get instance of actual form from MS Access in a Module (VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848814/how-to-get-instance-of-actual-form-from-ms-access-in-a-module-vba)

I have created a class module to try and take the data input in the `Text Box` from the currently active form and store the value of each `Text Box` in each property of the class, then reference that in my form's `On Click` save command.

```
Option Explicit

Public number As String
Public name As String

Public Function getData()

    Dim frmCurrentForm As Form
    Dim frmName As String

    Set frmCurrentForm = Screen.ActiveForm
    frmName = frmCurrentForm.Name

End Function
```

I am able to get the current active form's name, but am unsure where to go from here to get the form's `Text Box` property data input, which as an example, are named `textBox_Number` and `textBox_Name`?

The answer for the above issue states to do the following:

```
Public Sub mFormLoad(p_form As Form)
    'do stuff with p_form
end sub
```

But using the `p_form` object to access its property, I can only find the generic properties of a `Form`, and not specific properties tied to my active form, i.e. `textBox_Number` and `textBox_Name`.

Being new to VBA programming, can someone guide me through?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Controls` collection:

`p_form.Controls("textbox_Number").Value` should refer to the value of your textbox.

Alternatively, you could only take a specific form as a parameter:

```
Public Sub mFormLoad(p_form As Form_MyFormName)
    'do stuff with p_form
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks your first suggestion works!...can you elaborate more on the alternative?....you are saying if my form is named `frmMyForm`, then it would be `Public Sub mFormLoad(p_form As frmMyForm)`?

Comment: No, if your form is named _frmMyForm_, then it would be `Public Sub mFormLoad(p_form As Form_frmMyForm)`. That approach specifies that you're not taking a form with the generic _Form_ interface (which any form possesses) as a parameter, but that the parameter must possess the `Form_frmMyForm` interface. That way you can only pass one specific form to the sub.

Comment: sorry to ask this, still learning vba, but when I declared the `sub` as you suggested with `Form_frmMyForm`, I cannot access any of its properties, i.e. `p_form.` gives me nothing...is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The form needs to have a module. You can try adding [Option Explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2454583/7296893) to the top of your module to debug easily.